# ngx_lua how to remove http request header

Tags: nginx, openresty

There is a param named "RedirectURL" in http request header. I want to remove it in ngx_lua and then send this request to RedirectURL, here is some snippet in nginx.conf

```
location /apiproxytest {

           set_by_lua $redirectURL '
                    return ngx.req.get_headers()["RedirectURL"]
            ';

            header_filter_by_lua '
                     ngx.header["RedirectURL"] = nil;
            ';

            echo "1:" $redirectURL;

            set_by_lua $redirectURL2 '
                    return ngx.req.get_headers()["RedirectURL"]
            ';
            echo "2:" $redirectURL2;

            proxy_pass $redirectURL;
}
```

When I test it use

```
curl --header "RedirectURL:www.google.com" xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/apiproxytest
```

I get result:

```
1: www.google.com
2: www.google.com
```

I don't know where the wrong is. Who can help me figure it out? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usual mistake. You think that nginx directives are executed in the same order as in config file.
There are a lot phases of processing of nginx configuration files. Good, but long explanation: [Nginx directive execution order](http://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html#02-nginxdirectiveexecorder01)

> In their execution order the phases are post-read, server-rewrite,
>   find-config, rewrite, post-rewrite, preaccess, access, post-access,
>   try-files, content, and finally log.

```
set_by_lua - phase: rewrite
echo - phase: content
proxy_pass - phase: content
header_filter_by_lua - phase: output-header-filter
```

You may see unlisted phase - output-header-filter.
Also I know about output-body-filter.
These are special phases and implemented in different way then rewrite, contect etc phases.
I cannot find a documentation for these phases. Any help are welcome!
But obviously they cannot be early then content phase.

Your config's directives are executed in next order:

```
set_by_lua directives
echo and proxy_pass directives
header_filter_by_lua directives
```

So `ngx.header["RedirectURL"] = nil` really executed later and has no influence to your echo directives.

Answer (score 6):

[ngx.req.clear_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.clear_header)

```
location /apiproxytest {
    set_by_lua $redirectURL '
        local url = ngx.req.get_headers()["RedirectURL"]
        ngx.req.clear_header("RedirectURL")

        return url
    ';

    proxy_pass $redirectURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API `ngx.req.clear_header(header)` or `ngx.req.set_header(header, nil)`, which is